# Getting error when trying to start Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jvm, virtualbox, jvm-arguments

I am trying to start Tomcat from Ubuntu VirtualBox, but it wont start. The error, "Unrecognized VM option 'DoEscapeAnalysis'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.", is in the output log. I am able to run my server on my computer (also running Ubuntu but not a virtual machine) and I am pretty sure that I am using the same configurations. Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to solve it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Check if JVMs are compatible with each other. It sounds like a version mismatch.

Comment: I figured out the problem! I needed to add setenv.sh where I had to put "export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1000m" "